# Qlikview connectivity error with SSAS Database source

Tags: ssas, qlikview

Am hoping i can count on skill set of the experts in the house.
I have a BI solution developed with Microsoft Analysis Services (aka SSAS) and am trying to connect to it via qlikview, the error thrown is

> Ensure SQL Server browser is running

and upon ports opened it try to connect and endless asking for user credentials without browsing the cubes.

I have tried couple of suggested solutions such as :

- Firstly, the SQL Server browser is running on the said server
- Secondly, have opened up the port for SSAS using a fixed port as the instance is a named instance

Also, have opened up the port on which SQL Server browser runs.

Firewall has been switched off on the said port while remote connectivity has been allowed.

Yet the error persists.

Although I can connect with the SSAS database on the local machine.

The problem does lie with trying to connect to SSAS on a remote server connection.

N.B: Am using Qlikview version 11.20, SQL server 2012 while the remote server is Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 64 bit

Kindly be of help here please.

MB

Comment: Assuming you have Excel installed on the same machine as Qlikview let's make sure the issue is not with permissions or network or SSAS by connecting with Excel. Can you try this: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2828/using-excel-to-interact-with-a-ssas-cube/